# iOS MKMapview within UINavigationController within UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview, uipageviewcontroller

Following are the flow of application controller .

I have a A: `UIViewController`
that displays a B: `UIPageViewController`
and one of the B's controller is a C: `UINavigationController`
that have a root vc a D: `UIViewController` with a map-view in it.

A > B > C > D
So in that configuration the map view stays gray, I can see the apple legals link though (bottom left) but the tiles aren't loading.

If I do that configuration :
A > B > D
The map display correctly except that D is not part of my `UINavigationController` :(

Any idea ?

Comment: Kindly update screenshot if possible

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it has to do with that :
https://openradar.appspot.com/26259875

made a few UI tweak and its working now !